# How can Android background thread provide data to new activities?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, background, provider

I'm having trouble with http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html It's been touted as a great source of information on painless threading, but I'm still having trouble even after reading basic documentation on Activities.

Here's my problem: I am using Eclipse to modify some Android source code that already creates a thread and handler that runs in the background even when I switch to a new activity. What I want is to implement a way for this background thread to provide data to new activities. I've looked at .aidl and AsyncTask solutions without success.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your activities are in the same package/app, you could put a reference to the thread in the Application object so that it can be accessed from all of your Activities. You would need to create a custom Application subclass and reference it in your manifest.

If you are looking at activities from different packages you could use a broadcast receiver model or a bound service I guess.

Comment: Thanks @fleetway76 I might try that next time. What I did this time was to simply create a static variable, stored my data in it, and read from the other activity.

Comment: Thanks @fleetway76. I wish I understood your answer better, because I think maybe I should be doing that now instead of later.

Comment: So, you have the ability to provide a custom class that will be instantiated as the Application object for your program. This will be a one object per process relationship and it will effectively act as the container or root of your object tree. You can reference it by calling getApplication() from you activity. You can put whatever you like in your Application subclass and access it from your activities. You specify that your subclass should be used instead of the default one in your manifest file.

Comment: a little more explanation would be appreciated but I am accepting your answer. I can tell from the reading I've been doing that have outlined a good approach. I just need a little more help.